# How to detect the install directory of a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I have a Visual studio C# project and I have an installer that installs the files into whatever directory the user specifies. I also have another installer with localized language resources and I want that to be installed in the aforementioned directory.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? I think I have to do something with registry keys but I don't know what to do.

Edit: For the record, I found this page: [How to: Use a Registry Launch Condition to Specify a Target Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0z89y5d.aspx). And I followed the instructions and it did what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would create a registry subkey and value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ and then just read that key back in your second installer to decide where to put that.

Something like **HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyApplication**,

Then you make a string value called **InstallPath** and write the path from your first installer there.

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to have a look at [merge modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369820%28VS.85%29.aspx) for installing several components with one MSI.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  Your first installer would write it's install path to a well known registry key.  The second installer would read the path from that well known key and put it's dlls in the appropriate sub folders.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to go at it:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(a.CodeBase);
```

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. The thing is that I don't know very much about installers. All I have is a .vdproj file and I don't know how to put code in it. Sorry if this sounds stupid, but can you tell me how to add code to an installer?